# Laravel Mail attach binary data

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is there any way to attach a binary data as a file?

```
\Mail::send('test', [], function ($message) {
      $message->to('xxxxxx.@xx.com', 'X X')->subject('TEST');
      $message->attach($file_binary_data);
});
```

I have checked this, but email didn't send. Gave only a blank page with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

1, The Mail API based drivers such as Mailgun and Mandrill are often simpler and faster than SMTP servers.  You should register a mailgun or mandrill account firstly, or use your mail smtp (You can get the smtp info in your email settings)

2, the 'test' view file must exist in your 'resources/views' directory.

3, $file_binary_data must exist in your local file system.

Answer (score 0):

Use attachData method:

```
\Mail::send('test', [], function ($message) {
      $message->to('xxxxxx.@xx.com', 'X X')->subject('TEST');
      //$message->attach($file_binary_data);
      $message->attachData($file_binary_data, 'my-file-name.pdf', []);
});
```